# Opengl texture rendered as solid color,why?

Tags: opengl, textures

her is my vertex array and texture coordinate..

```
float POS[]=
{
    -0.5,-0.5,-1.0,
    0.5,-0.5,-1.0,
    0.5,0.5,-1.0,
    -0.5,0.5,-1.0
};

float texCoords[] = {
0.0,0.0,
1.0,0.0,
1.0,1.0,
0.0,1.0
};
```

here is my texture creation

```
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    openglTexBuff=stbi_load("lena.jpg",&w,&h,&c,0);


    glGenTextures(1,&TexID);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,TexID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,w,h,GL_FALSE,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,openglTexBuff);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
    stbi_image_free(openglTexBuff);'
```

and these are my shaders

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core 

layout(location = 0) in vec4 positions;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoords;
uniform mat4 translation_matrix; //inactive shader variables..
uniform mat4 rotation_matrix;

mat4 model_matrix; //
mat4 projection_matrix;
out vec4 pos;
out vec2 frag_TexCoord;

void main()
{

rotation_matrix;

gl_Position=rotation_matrix*translation_matrix*positions; //translation matrix operated with POS vector..
pos=positions;
frag_TexCoord=texCoords;
translation_matrix;

}



#shader fragment  
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) out vec4 color;
in vec4 pos;
in vec2 frag_TexCoord;rag_TexCoord;
uniform float col;
uniform sampler2D  a_texture;
void main()
{
col;
a_texture;

color=texture(a_texture,frag_TexCoord);

}
```

when i use (solid)color instead of texture in shader..everything works fine but when i use shader it gives solid color instead of texture..It seems like my whole tex is super-zoomed to output single color

here is draw call

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    box.shader.setUniformat4x4("translation_matrix",translation);
    //box.shader.setUniformat4x4("rotation_matrix",rotation_arr);
    box.shader.setUniform1f("col",1.0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,TexID);
    box.shader.setUniform1i("a_texture",0);
    box.render();
```

box.render

```
void render()
    {
        vertices.bind();
        indices.bind();
        shader.bind();
        glDrawElements(render_As,vertices.getSize(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,NULL);
        vertices.unbind();
        indices.unbind();

    }
```

Comment: Your title looks like you are trying to render a single colour instead of a texture, would be better to rephrase it and make it an actual question, so you can reach more people to help you.

Comment: Could you suggest one??

Comment: Your new title seems better, remember to keep it simple, something like "Why does my opengl texture render as a single colour?" or "Why is my opengl texture not being rendered?" or something like that.

Comment: Start by checking for errors (first after uploading the texture). glGetError() should return GL_NO_ERROR if everything is fine, otherwise it returns the error code. Also check if openglTexBuff is null after loading the jpeg. Basically check everything that could fail.

Comment: @MaikSemder everything is fine, image is uploaded to GPU well in texture slot 0..any possible mess with texture coordinate of internal format??

Comment: I tried changing texture image,but it seems like gl is rendering acent color of whole texture

Comment: On stack exchange sites, the fact that you mark an answer as "accepted" is enough to make it "solved": no need to change the title to reflect this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoords;
```

**This is happening because your texture coordinate attribute is not at index 1 in your C/C++ code**.

Typically one of three things will cause this.

1. You're using the legacy glTexCoordPointer to set it up, which does not alias to index 1.
2. You're using a glVertexAttribPointer call with an index other than 1.
3. You're not actually setting a pointer for texture coordinates at all.

The default value for an unspecified attribute is {0, 0, 0, 1}, which - when that attribute is used as a texture coordinate - will sample from the bottom-left of the texture every time.

Comment: Yeah!!! my texcoord index was not at 1....This really pissed off my mind,By the way what does layout location describe about??

Comment: @ShivanshuRaj - see https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index and https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_explicit_attrib_location.txt - but SE sites are not for extended discussions nor for tutorials, so I recommend that you read the documentation and if you have trouble with anything specific, ask another question.